# How do I find the fourier series for the function f(t) = sin t?

Tags: fourier-series

How do I find a fourier series for the function of period $2\pi$ satisfying
$$f(t)= \begin{cases}\sin t &0 \le t<\pi\\0 &\pi\le t<2\pi\end{cases} $$

Do I find $b_n$ as usual (because it's an odd function) and then give the Dirichlet conditions? I'm a bit thrown by the zero.

Comment: You can save yourself a bit of calculation by noting that$$f(x) = \max(\sin x, 0) = \tfrac{1}{2}(\sin x + |\sin x|),$$the right-hand side being the decomposition into odd and even parts.

Answer (score 3):

The function is not odd.  Since its period is given as $2\pi$, the function is also $0$ from $-\pi$ to $0$.  So you'll have to grind out the integrals

$$a_n =\frac{1}{\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(x) \cos \frac{n\pi x}{\pi} \; dx =\frac{1}{\pi} \int_{0}^{\pi} \sin(x) \cos nx\; dx$$

and so on.

Comment: Can't the question have defined $f$ to be odd, implying that it's $\sin x$ for $-\pi < x < 0$, $0$ for $-2 \pi < x \leq -\pi$ etc?  
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/zkxyg1sukn

Comment: @Twenty-sixcolours  That would make the period $4\pi.$

Comment: Ah my bad, thanks!

Comment: I hoping to avoid having to find both $a_n$ and $b_n$, what do I do with the zero? That's my main concern

Comment: The difference between the first and second integrals in my answer is the interval of integration.   The zero eliminates the part from $-\pi$ to $\pi.$